# z-index not working with css3 drop down nav

Tags: css, z-index

I am modifying a css3 nav that i found in a tutorial and I am having trouble with the z-indexing.

Please check out the nav here:

http://cafemeetup.com/testArea/nav/

If you rollover either of the 2 nav items, you can see that the z-indexing of the drop down box is higher than the link that spawned it.
This is not true as I have made the z-index of the rollover box lower in the stacking order.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the drop down box fall underneath the link so the the drop shadow of the drop down box is not visible on top. I want the link and drop down box to meld into one and I think by making the link sit on top of the drop down box, I can achieve this.

It is done here at Shopify:

http://www.shopify.com/ (rollover 'resources')

Anyway, hope someone can shed light on this.
I am assuming that the problem lies in the fact that the object I am trying to add z-indexes to are hovers and also that they are not regular divs as such.

Anyway, thank you for at least reading all this. I appreciate your time,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a demo for you on jsFiddle. Try moving your background and z-index style to the .drop link instead of the list item in your code and it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/sTsrb/

Comment: Thanks Andri. I tried that and it didn't work but it did spawn an idea in my head that finally worked. I solved this by just stripping out the right hand nab item and simplifying the code to just one drop down and renaming everything again to stuff that is more easy to read.

Then I added the z-index (higher number) to the li:hover state for the tab and the z-index to the drop down nab div class (lower number). 

It is pretty much what I had but css didn't like that I didn't put the z-index of the tab (higher number) on the li:hover selector. zzzzz Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are applying your `z-index:999` to the `<li class="menu_right">` and then applying `z-index:1` to the `<div class="dropdown_1column align_right">` child element. If you want it to appear underneath the `<li>`, make it a sibling, not a child.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however, I am not sure what you mean by putting z-index:999 to the <li class="menu_right"> because I don't think that it is. Also I understand sibling versus child now but not sure how to implement it in this case. Sorry but thank you

Comment: The `z-index:999` is applied literally to `#menu li`